# Google Apps Script problems formatting PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

I'm using GAS to generate a PDF of a given sheet within a source spreadsheet.
The way I go about it is to first copy the given sheet onto a new spreadsheet file, which I call "intermediate", style it, and then get it PDF'd with `fileToPDF.getAs("application/pdf");`.

The file gets created and it has everything I want it to have, except for two issues:

- I've applied some borders to some ranges using `sheet.getRange(borderRange).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);` and they do show without issues in the "intermediate" file. However, they disappear in the PDF.
- I've merged some sets of ranges and there is no problem there, but there is one big exception, where the last merged range in the sheet doesn't show as one merged cell in the PDF.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```js
function crearPdf() {
  const ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(ssID).getParents().next();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getActiveSheet();

  const sourceRange = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getMaxRows(), ws.getMaxColumns());
  const numFac = ws.getRange("D20");
  const sourceValues = sourceRange.getDisplayValues();
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.create("temp " + Date());
  const destSheet = dest.getSheets()[0];
  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());

  destRange.setValues(sourceValues);
  styleSheet(destSheet);

  const destId = dest.getId();
  const fileToPDF = DriveApp.getFileById(destId);
  const fileAsPDF = fileToPDF.getAs("application/pdf");
  const newFile = DriveApp.createFile(fileAsPDF).setName("Factura " + numFac.getValue() + ' - ' + " '21");
  // const fileUrl = newFile.getDownloadUrl();

  newFile.moveTo(destFolder);
  // fileToPDF.setTrashed(true);
}

function styleSheet(sheet) {
  // Declaring our constants
  const arrToMerge = ["B24:G24", "B25:G25", "B26:G26", "B40:H40", "B20:C20", "B21:C21", "B22:C22"];
  const arrToBorder = ["B20:D22", "B24:H26", "G27:H28"];
  const arrToBold = ["B11", "B20", "B21", "B22", "B24", "B31", "B33", "B34", "B35", "B36", "G28", "H3", "H24", "H28"];

  // Direct tweaks
  sheet.setHiddenGridlines(true);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 15);
  sheet.getDataRange().setFontFamily("Open Sans");
  sheet.getRange("B40").setWrap(true);
  sheet.getRange("B40:B47").setFontSize(9);
  sheet.autoResizeRows(40, 1);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(3, 54);
  // sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 79);
  sheet.setRowHeights(37, 3, 7);
  // sheet.setRowHeights(40, 7, 16);
  sheet.getRange("h24").setHorizontalAlignment("right");
  sheet.getRange("B24:H24").setBackground("#666666").setFontColor("white");

  // Loops for multiple ranges tweaks
  for (let range of arrToMerge) {
    sheet.getRange(range).merge();
  }
  for (let cell of arrToBold) {
    sheet.getRange(cell).setFontWeight("bold");
  }
  for (let range of arrToBorder) {
    sheet.getRange(range).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
  }
}
```

I've also removed some cells from the original file to make it easier to understand (haven't really deleted all the references in the code, so don't be surprised if you see references to cells that look empty)

And the pictures below correspond to:

Original spreadsheet

[image]

Intermediate file (this file is generated because in the original spreadsheet there are many sheets)

[image]

Final PDF

[image]

And finally, a [link to a public spreadsheet with dummy data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cny5vEQwq_3wwmWhcsSSiiG8A8AsbkhjM9VV_fq-xSo/edit?usp=sharing)

Is there some known weird behaviour with the `getAs("application/pdf") method? Is there a way that I can make it work properly?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

### Instead of using `getAs()` export the sheet to pdf

You can do it by

- Creating the export link `"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+destId+"/export?"`
- Using [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)
- Creating a new file from the [blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file?hl=en#getblob) of the response
- Use [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) to make sure that the formatting of the spreadsheet finished before the export as pdf is performed.

Sample:

```js
function crearPdf() {

  const ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(ssID).getParents().next();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getActiveSheet();

  const sourceRange = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getMaxRows(), ws.getMaxColumns());
  const numFac = ws.getRange("D20");
  const sourceValues = sourceRange.getDisplayValues();
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.create("temp " + Date());
  const destSheet = dest.getSheets()[0];
  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());

  destRange.setValues(sourceValues);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  styleSheet(destSheet);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  const destId = dest.getId();
  
  
 //  THIS IS NEW
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+destId+"/export?";

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  
  // adjust the following parametrers as desired
  
  
  + '&size=letter'                                   // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=true'                                // orientation, false for landscape
  +'&top_margin=0.50'
  +'&bottom_margin=0.50' 
  +'&left_margin=0.50' 
  +'&right_margin=0.50'
  + '&gridlines=false' 
  // other parameters if you need
  /*
  + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'                       // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'             // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false'                               // hide page numbers 
  + '&fzr=false'                                     // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                                         // the sheet's Id
  */

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, 
   {
    headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    },
    muteHttpExceptions:true
  });
  
  const newFile =  DriveApp.createFile(response.getBlob().setName("Factura " + numFac.getValue() + ' - ' + " '21"));
  // const fileUrl = newFile.getDownloadUrl();

  newFile.moveTo(destFolder);
  // fileToPDF.setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka for your answer. Even though it provides a nice and elegant way to create a PDF with more control over the ouput file, none of my issues are resolved using this method.

Comment: I tested this solution in my environment and it works without issues. I am wondering if in your case due to the asynchronisity of Apps Script the pdf is created before the formatting of the spreadsheet finishes (due to the amount of requests carried out by function `styleSheet()`). In this case, you can force the script to wait for SpreadsheetApp to finish by using [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) - see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the addition! It seems very useful. However, in my case it has made no difference after I moved around my for loops (see my own answer) so there was something to that since now all styles are applied with and without SpreadsheetApp.flush(). I will, no doubt use it in the future but in this case, both the way I was doing it originally and your way work just as well. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out, the order in which you format your spreadsheet using Apps Script matters, and that's why I was losing some of the formatting.

The way I've devised my formatting involves having several arrays of cells to which to apply certain tweaks, such as merging cells, setting borders, setting bold font, etc, and using a for-of loop to iterate through each cell range. As it happens, it seems that these for-of loops have to be the first thing you do if you have other tweaks to do, otherwise they don't seem to work.

Thanks everyone for your help!